# Centos 7 doesn't boot after a forced power off

Tags: centos

I had to power off the computer by unplugging the electricity plug.
Now Centos 7 boots only in the `Emergency mode` asking me to check `journalctl -xb'.

Inside, there are some red lines such as:

- `Failed to mount /boot.efi`
- `Failed to mount RPC Pipe File System.`

How can I fix all those to be able to boot correctly? IS it still trustable? Should I reinstall it?

When I try to `systemctl default`, I get `Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message or more information.`

Comment: You might need to run fsck on the EFI volume, which is fat32. You could also add “nofail” to the mount options.

Comment: I tired to mount it but `unknown filesystem type 'vfat`.

Comment: Sounds like the kernel you are booted into doesn’t support vfat. Try an earlier kernel from the grub boot loader.

Comment: The kernel is `3.10.0.1127.el7` the latest for centos 7, it was working perfectly before the power outage and I have a different server with the same kernel, no problem. Why it can't find `vfat` anymore.. I tried `modprobe -v vfat` but that command doesn't return anything. And `lsmod` doesn't show `vfat` module.

Comment: a `find` under `/lib/modules/3.10.....` shows a `kernel/fs/fat/vfat.ko.xz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jsbillings thanks for your help!

- Centos 7 was booting exclusively in the `Emergency mode`
- `systemctl --failed` showed the `/boot/efi` partition can't be mounted because `vfat` is unknown.

Solution:

1. `fsck /dev/nvme0n1p1` to clean the error bit of the EFI partition
2. `modprobe vfat` didn't work
3. Doing `depmod -a` and a reboot `systemctl reboot` fixed and I can now boot correctly.

Comment: After trying a bunch of other things this finally worked! Thank you for sharing.